# How to use bind mount in docker with angular application?

Tags: angular, docker, mounted-volumes

I am dockerizing an angular application. But I want to use bind mount for code sharing purpose. I am running following command which makes container up and running and entire application works completely fine. But when I make changes in my local repository, it doesn`t get reflected on a webpage.

This is how I run the container

```
docker run -d -p 4200:80 --rm --name frontend -v E:\dir1\dir2\subdirectory:/app image_name:image_tag
```

```
#Dockerfile
FROM node:14-alpine as node

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=node app/dist/angular-frontend usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Your Dockerfile is well suited for taking your app and packaging it, so it can be deployed with Nginx. What you want to do is to have the source on your host and have your container dynamically react to changes in the source. Those goals are not compatible.

Comment: For day-to-day development, I'd suggest using plain Node without Docker.  This is doubly true for a front-end application, where you can't usefully use features like Docker networking.